# Rails Displaying data form HABTM realationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I’m new to rails and having problem with figuring out how to diplay data with HABTM relationship.
1. The situation is I am trying to create simple tool where I have Devices which are assigned Model and each Model can have specific spare Parts. 
2. I've managed to create HABTM relationship and table to assign models to spare parts and save it to DB.
2. I want to be able to create tickets for devices where during creating the ticket user should be able to order spare parts (but only from the list of parts for this specific model od device!).
3. I got stuck how during creating the ticket display the parts for only the specific model of device (I do pass model_id as a parm in url). Probably after all to save it to databease I would need to use additional HABTM table tickets_parts but now I only want to know how to display this.
4. I am getting undefined method `models' for #

Many thanks in advance for suggestions and help on this issue!

Models look like:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :parts
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :model
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :models
    has_and_belongs_to_many :order_tickets
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :models
end
```

my tickets/_form.html.erb looks like:

```
  <%= form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>
  <% if @ticket.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@ticket.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ticket from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @ticket.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :counter %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :counter %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :issue %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :issue %>
  </div>

<!-- Here i want to display the spare parts only for the specific model --> 

  <% Part.models(:model_id).each do |x| %>
  <%= x.name %>
  <% end %>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve model in an instance variable in the controller, and then in the form you can use:

> ```
> <% @model.parts.each do |x| %>
>     <%= x.name %>
>   <% end %>
> ```

Note: "Model" is not a reserved word, but I would advise not to use it as a class name.

Comment: I've put 
   def commonstuff
    @model = Model.find(params[:model_id])
  end
in the tickets controller and before_action :commonstuff. But now getting: undefined method `parts' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Hi, then you should check that the model instance in the db matches the id value you are passing.

Comment: Yes i matches. I've observed something else when I just wanted to print model variable using  <%= @model.inspect %> it still shows Nil so I suppose it causes the problem...